# Is there a way to show canvas triggering the div to get the object in the script?

Tags: javascript, html, webrtc

I am creating a Whiteboard to my Video Conferencing System usign WebRTC, what I want to add right now is the whiteboard. I have the following codes which includes the div tag, which is the trigger part to show the window or whiteboard.

```
 <div class="video-mute-icon" id="wb-window" title="Whiteboard" style="cursor: pointer;">
      <i class="fa fa-video" id="self_wBoard"></i>
 </div>
```

Next I have the canvas html

```
 <div id="demo">
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <div id="main-container" class="enx-layout-container">
            <canvas id="wb"></canvas>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3" >
        <div id="localStreamPlayer"></div>
        <div id="remoteStreamPlayer"></div>
        <div id="canvasStreamPlayer"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Finally I have this script

```
<script>
    var wbObject  =  new EnxWb(
        {   canvasId: 'wb', // id of the canvas 
            initialWidth: 1000,
            initialHeight: 500,
            scheme : 'custom',
            custom: {
                bgColor : 'red',        /* WB Backbround */
                toolbarBGColor : 'black',   /* Toolbar Background */
                brushColor:'black',     /* Default Brush Color */
                icon : {            /* Toolbar Icon definition */
                    size: 'medium', /* Enum: small,large,medium */
                    type: 'rounded-square', /* Enum:  square,rounded-square */
                    BGColor: '#f3f3f3', /* Tool Background */
                    FGColor: '#000000', /* Tool Foreground */
                    border: '1px solid grey'/* Tool Border */
                }
            }
        }
    );

    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = wbObject.canvasId;

</script>
```

I have imported JS files as well such as:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/EnxRtc.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/EnxWb.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/confo.js"></script>
```

Image:
[This image refer to the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LMHpB.png)

Comment: `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML` takes an HTML string, and as part of the assignment converts that HTML markup into live DOM content. I'm pretty sure `wbObject.canvasId` is not an HTML string, so can you explain what you expect this line to do? The canvas is already, it's already in div#demo, so why would you even need to do anything in that respect? (Also, note that in HTML5, you don't specify the type of a script unless it's _not_ javascript. But you should definitely use the [async and defer attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-async))

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans - hello sir, I am expecting to show that canvas using the div class please see the image I have updated above. Thanks